# React state magically changes for no reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, momentjs, fetch-api

I am using React for a calendar application. I am fetching data from API for certain dates to get only 1 week worth of data at a time from database.

When I fetch from API like this:

```
export default class CalendarApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    months: moment.months(),
    day: moment.weekdays(),
    daysPerMonth: moment().daysInMonth(),
    startDate: moment(),
    date: moment().year(2017).month(0).date(1).format('l'),
    firstWeekDay: 0,
    data: [],
    minDate: moment().year(2017).month(0).date(1),
    maxDate: moment().year(2018).month(11).date(31)
  };
  componentDidMount() {


    const startDate = this.state.startDate.day(this.state.firstWeekDay).unix();
    const endDate = this.state.startDate.day(this.state.firstWeekDay).add(1, 'week').unix();
    console.log(`I am fetching data between ${moment.unix(startDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY")} and ${moment.unix(endDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY")}`);

    // console.log(this.state.startDate.day(this.state.firstWeekDay));

    axios.get(`http://localhost/api/date?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`).then((response) => {
      this.setState(() => ({ data: response.data}));
    });
  };
```

Then startDate magically changes (it adds 1 week like I have on endDate variable even though I never use setState for this).
As a result my calendar app is broken and it always fetches a week before I need and not the current week. 
For example if my calendar displays days between 05/20/2018 and 05/26/2018 I get data from API for days between 05/13/2018 and 05/20/2018.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly mutating the state in componentDidMount and hence it gets updated. use the `.clone()` method on moment object to clone it before making any change

```
componentDidMount() {
    let startDate = 
this.state.startDate.clone()
    startDate = startDate.day(this.state.firstWeekDay).unix();
    const endDate = this.state.startDate.clone().day(this.state.firstWeekDay).add(1, 'week').unix();
    console.log(`I am fetching data between ${moment.unix(startDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY")} and ${moment.unix(endDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY")}`);

    // console.log(this.state.startDate.day(this.state.firstWeekDay));

    axios.get(`http://localhost/api/date?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`).then((response) => {
      this.setState(() => ({ data: response.data}));
    });
  };
```

Comment: It lets me clone startDate, but when I use startDate.clone() in endDate variable then it throws an error: "startDate.clone is not a function".

Comment: use startDate from state since clone doesn't work on unix value

Comment: Yea, thanks I already did that. I got it working now, thank you!

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

I never used moment but I found this in the documentation :

> Note: It should be noted that moments are mutable. Calling any of the manipulation methods will change the original moment.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/

so when you call

`this.state.startDate.day(this.state.firstWeekDay).add(1, 'week').unix();`

It changes your start date and return it.

Hope it helps you.